# Rust Destructuring struct reference vs Destructuring struct

Tags: rust

The following code works

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32
}

fn area(shape: &Rectangle) -> u32 {
    let Rectangle{width, height} = shape;
    width * height
}

fn main() {
    let rec1 = Rectangle {width: 5, height: 10};
    println!("Area {}", area(&rec1));
    println!("Rec {:?}", rec1);
}
```

But replacing the reference to struct `&Shape` with dereference reference `*&Shape` also works (e.g `let Rectangle{width, height} = shape; --> let Rectangle{width, height} = *shape;`).

I have no idea why both work, is there some implicit dereferencing when destructing? I though `&Shape` reference only points to where `Shape` is in memory, whereas `*&Shape` is `Shape` itself. `width` and `height` are properties of `struct Rectangle` rather than the reference `&Rectangle`.

Comment: Aren't you making a new Rectangle (called rec1), which is a copy of shape, instead of destructuring? If you wanted to destructure you would need to use match, I think. See [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_structures.html).

Comment: @hkBst `let` also performs pattern-matching, but only allows *irrefutable* patterns. The code does indeed destructure `shape`, that is not the issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I have no idea why both work, is there some implicit dereferencing when destructing?

This is a (convenient but confusing) consequence of Edition 2018's [match ergonomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md): when matching on reference types, the compiler will implicitly add references and deref so things are about right.

Here what happens in `area` is that `width` and `height` are `&u32` not `u32`, the compiler effectively interprets your code as:

```rust
let &Rectangle{ ref width, ref height } = shape;
```

If you're not using something like rust-analyzer which can surface this information in your editor directly, a common trick is to write something like:

```rust
let x: () = var
```

the compilation error will tell you what the type of `var` is (unless it's `()`).

> I though &Shape reference only points to where Shape is in memory, whereas *&Shape is Shape itself.

That is true, however in the context of a *pattern* that doesn't necessarily mean the structure is moved. Here because the fields of `Rectangle` are both `Copy` the compiler can destructure the "owned" struct without needing to move it, it can just copy the fields. Which is essentially what a simple attribute access would do (`shape.width` is `u32`).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have tried this in rust 2021, rust-analyzer told me, I get two reference: `wdith` and `height`. So I look at `width * height` line, there are two reference to u32, and `*` operator, aka [`std::ops::Mul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Mul.html) have implement multipy of two `&u32`.